# How to convert Date 2022-02-02 (yyyy-dd-MM) to 02-Feb-2022 in Java?

Tags: java, date, date-formatting

Date 2022-02-02 (yyyy-dd-MM)  to 02-Feb-2022 in Java

need help in converting Date 2022-02-02 to format 02-Feb-2022

Comment: Where did you put your search engine? Please learn that you are supposed to search before asking a question here and when you post a question, tell us what your search brought up and specify how it fell short of solving your problem. It’s for your own sake since (1) you often find a better answer faster that way (2) it allows us to give preciser and more focused answers. It also tends to prevent or at least reduce the number of downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LocalDate.parse("2022-02-02", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-dd-MM")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
```

Comment: Depends on his locale.  In America, it would be month first.  In Europe, day first.

Comment: Fair enough.  Process is the same though which I think is what he's really after.  I'll edit it though,

Comment: The order yyyy-dd-MM doesn’t agree with any standard order I have ever seen anywhere in the world. So I may still suspect it’s an error. Most Europeans put day before month but then year last. For example 24/03/22 or 24 mars 2022.

Comment: Basically the correct answer. You should specify a locale for the formatter used for formatting to make sure that `Feb` comes in the desired language.